# (Scikit - Python) ImportError: No module named scipy

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to install Scikit and run a python file that only has:

```
import sklearn
```

To check if Scikit works. This is the error I get:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "hello-world.py", line 1, in 
>       import sklearn
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/**init**.py", line 57, in 
>       from .base import clone
>     File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 9, in 
>       from scipy import sparse
>   ImportError: No module named scipy

I have been at this for hours now. My python version is **Python 2.7.11**

which -a python

gives me this:

```
/usr/local/bin/python
/usr/bin/python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
/Users/Iliad/anaconda/bin/python
```

I had had Python 3.5 Installed before, but downloaded Anaconda for 2.7, but can't make sure it is set to work with that version.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will start with

```
python --version
```

Just to be sure

and then in python repl. Use this

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

This would give you something like :

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
```

Check in all the dist-packages for scipy. My guess is that it is not there. 
If you have any other "dist-packages" type of folder then you should add that to your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I get `['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']` back, but none of those directories have scipy inside of them. Also **/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python** Does not exist! And the python version is Python 2.7.11

Comment: Also, although the Python.framework doesn't exist, the python IDE runs perfectly

Comment: Quick solution could be to do pip install sklearn. The other way (which I think you should do ) is to figure out 1. Where did anaconda install your dist-packaged (It;s usually under /User/<your name>/ anaconda/lib< ) and 2. Add /Users/Iliad/anaconda/bin/python in start of your path so that this python is picked up first.  And finally 3.After you figure out where is the site-packages for anaconda add them to pythonpath.

Comment: Option 1 helped me out. Thank you so much, works perfectly now!